# What is the meaning of '.' in the cpio file

Tags: filenames, cpio

This is my the content of my rootfs.cpio file:

```
[root@xilinx output]#  cpio -idv  < rootfs.cpio
.
init
dev
dev/console
1149 blocks
```

What is `.` here ?

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the current directory. All directories on Linux file systems contain the hardlinks `.` and `..` (the parent directory). For example:

```
 $ ls -a / | head -4
.
..
bin
boot
```

This is what enables you to do `cd ../` to move to the parent directory or use constructs like `find .` to search the current directory (though the `.` is actually implied in `find`).